# What aspect of a a JavaFX animation is missing from this?

Tags: animation, javafx

I am trying to get this simple animation to play over an image background however I cannot get it to start.
 I have tried adding in a button as well as using playFromStart() instead of play().
I also tried adding in the set orientation to the path, I didn't think it would do anything because I'm just moving a circle, and it hasn't helped.
I also tried messing with the timing and number of repetitions of the animation just in case somehow it was just all happening really quickly or slowly and I just missed it.
I feel like I'm probably missing something really simple but from everything that I've looked at, all the things that the examples have, I also have.

The background image also went away when I added the button, for that I have tried moving it up and other things but I feel like this is also a simple issue that my brain has just glazed over.

```
package javafxapplication10;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class JavaFXApplication10 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {


            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.sizeToScene();
            ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(image);
            scene.setFill(pattern);        

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            Circle cir = new Circle (19);            
            cir.setLayoutX(170);
            cir.setLayoutY(100);
            cir.setFill(Color.KHAKI);
            pane.getChildren().add(cir);

            Path path1 = new Path();


            path1.getElements().add(new MoveTo(170,650));
            path1.getElements().add(new MoveTo(1335,650));
            path1.getElements().add(new MoveTo(1335,100));
            PathTransition pl = new PathTransition();
            pl.setDuration(Duration.seconds(8));
            pl.setPath(path1);
            pl.setNode(cir);
            pl.setCycleCount(1);
            //pl.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
            pl.setAutoReverse(false);
            //pl.play();

             Button begin = new Button("Begin");
            begin.setLayoutX(780);
            begin.setLayoutY(105);
            begin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent press) {
                pl.play();

            }
            }); 
            pane.getChildren().add(begin);


    }

    Image image = new Image("file:Figure one.png");

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene (pane,1474,707);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PathTransition` only moves the node along a path that would actually be drawn. `MoveTo` elements do not draw anything, but simply set the current position. You need to use `LineTo` (and/or `ClosePath`) to draw something in the `Path`. Furthermore `PathTransition` sets the translate poperties, not the layout properties, i.e. final position of the circle is determined by adding the layout coordinates to the coodrinates provided by the `Path`. Therefore you should either position the `Circle` using the translate properties or start the path at `(0, 0)`:

```
Path path1 = new Path(
        new MoveTo(0, 0),
        new LineTo(0, 550),
        new LineTo(1165, 550),
        new LineTo(1165, 0),
        new ClosePath()
);
// path1.getElements().add(new MoveTo(170,650));
// path1.getElements().add(new MoveTo(1335,650));
// path1.getElements().add(new MoveTo(1335,100));
```